# htaccess, redirect to https for a specific file and to non-www https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've a site to work and trying to make redirect by htaccess for few days. I've searched the net and found good works, especially in this site, but altough I've tried almost every possibilities, I've could not achieve what I want to do.

My need is redirect all site to non-www http, including https, except for only one file. Let's say redirect 
**http ://www.example.com/.../....php?a=...**
**https ://www.example.com/.../....php?a=...**
**https ://example.com/.../....php?a=...**
to 
***http ://example.com/.../....php?a=...***

However, only one specific file
 
**http ://www.example.com/.../theSpecificFile.php?a=...**
**https ://www.example.com/.../theSpecificFile.php?a=...**
**http ://example.com/.../theSpecificFile.php?a=...**
should be redirected to
***https ://example.com/.../theSpecificFile.php?a=...***

To do these, I've wrote many htaccess files but in each case, I couldn't achieve my needs. e.g. At the last htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks        
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteBase /    

ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404.php    

#force https for certain pages        
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on    
RewriteRule ^(theSpecificFile\.php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]    

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on    
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]    

#redirect www.example.com to example.com (or any other subdomain)    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

By this htaccess file, 

when I try to **https ://www** I get ***Unsecure or Untrusted connection*** (I'm translating from another language, hope it might be true translation) with  ssl_error_bad_cert_domain
and when I try to access to the **theSpecificFile.php** I get error defining "***infine loop***" (again I hope this might be a true translation).

This is really frustrating for me, so, any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Look, here you redirect `theSpecificFile.php` to its https version, but then the second redirect rule triggers and redirects the browser back to http, and from there the first rule redirects back to https... That's why you're getting the infinite loop.

And ssl_error_bad_cert_domain means the certificate isn't for this domain, so you might need to check if you're using the right one.

Comment: Ok, after changing first and second "RewriteCond and RewriteRule" lines' places, when try to enter example.com, redirected to "https://example/com"

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteConf %{REQUEST_URI} !=/theSpecificFile.php
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteConf %{REQUEST_URI} !=/theSpecificFile.php   
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

#force https for certain pages  
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(theSpecificFile\.php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]` tried htaccess with example.com and get https ://example/com

Answer (score 0):

You can use that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/theSpecificFile\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]    

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /theSpecificFile\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Change [R=302,L] to [R=301,L] when everything works well